# String Comparison Python

Tags: python

I have 4 lists. I am working with `lst`, `lst2`, `lst3`, and `mainlist`. All 3 of the lst's have been split into 4 letter strings, such as `ACTG`, `CTGA` etc., where it takes the first 4 letters, and makes a string, then moves one letter over from the first and makes another 4 letter string. `mainlist` has all of its possible 4 letter strings found and saved such as: `AAAA` or `AATG`, etc. My goal is to find any outcomes from `mainlist` that exist in all 3 of my lst's, with at most 1 letter mismatch. For example, `AAAA` in `mainlist` and `AATA` in all three of the lst's. I am honestly not sure how to do this as I am very new to python. I know I need to compare them somehow but not sure the correct code to use.

My code so far:

```
import itertools

# Creates 3 lists, one with each of the input strings
lst = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'A', 'G']
lst2 = ['T', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G']
lst3 = ['G', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'G', 'T', 'T']

# Creates all the different permutations of length 4 of each of the 3 input strings
itertools.permutations(lst, 4)
itertools.permutations(lst2, 4)
itertools.permutations(lst3, 4)


# Function to  make all possible length 4 combos of mainList
def splitmainlist():
    mainlist = ['A', 'C', 'T', 'G']
    return list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(mainlist, 4))


# lists for the input strings when they are split
splitinputString1 = []
splitinputString2 = []
splitinputString3 = []

sequence_size = 4

# Takes the first 4 values of my lst, lst2, lst3, appends it to my split input strings, then increases the sequence by 1
for i in range(len(lst) - sequence_size + 1):
    sequence = ''.join(lst[i: i + 4])
    splitinputString1.append(sequence)

for i in range(len(lst2) - sequence_size + 1):
    sequence = ''.join(lst2[i: i + 4])
    splitinputString2.append(sequence)

for i in range(len(lst3) - sequence_size + 1):
    sequence = ''.join(lst3[i: i + 4])
    splitinputString3.append(sequence)


def intersectfound():
    return set(splitmainlist()).intersection(set(splitinputString1), set(splitinputString2),
                                                  set(splitinputString3))


print(intersectfound)
```

Comment: I feel like I'm watching GATTACA!  `'AAAA' in mainlist` is an example of finding a `str` in a `list`

Comment: @Trenton_M It's just `'AAAA' in mainlist`.  The `is` shouldn't be there.

Comment: Is the example in your post supposed to have any match? Maybe you could you add other examples to clarify the problem. (i.e. input & expected output)

Comment: Doesn't `intersectfound()` find strings that are in all four lists? What happens if you change `print(intersectfound)` to `print(intersectfound())`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that counts the number of mismatched letters in two strings, and returns true/false based on the number of mismatches.  (This assumes both strings are the same length and that positioning is important, i.e. ACTG is not a match for GTCA, even though both strings have the same letters.)

I think a function like this is your missing piece.

```
def is_close_match(s1, s2):
    mismatches = 0
    for i in range(0, len(s1)):
        if s1[i] != s2[i]:
            mismatches += 1
    if mismatches > 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't tried it yet but this looks like what i need.  As I said I am really new to Python, basically attempting to learn the language and write a program at the same time for my software engineering course.